# Am I misunderstanding the Python documentation?

Tags: python

Although not absolutely necessary, I thought it would be nice to have a multiprocessing Queue that I could use in the style of a Work Manager.

This is what I wrote:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue

class WMQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *_):
        self.close()
```

This induces the following exception:

```
TypeError: method expected 2 arguments, got 3
```

The reason is that multiprocessing.Queue is a method.

However, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) for Queue is as follows:

```
class multiprocessing.Queue([maxsize])
```

In fact, the Queue method returns an object of type *multiprocessing.queues.Queue* which, as I can't find any documentation for it, is probably unsafe to [try to] subclass.

I know how I can re-write my class so that it could be used as WM but that's not the point. If Queue was a class, as documented, then I should be able to simply subclass it.

Or am I misunderstanding Python documentation?

Comment: The question title is very vague without knowing the context (multiprocessing, queues): (1) intended behavior of a Work Manager (closing queue on exit)  (2) implementation attempted (subclass multiprocessing.Queue), (3) exception raised (TypeError), (4) concrete question the docs couldn't correctly answer (How to subclass from Queue). Can you improve the title and tags to be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to inherit from something, inherit from [`multiprocessing.queues.Queue`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58d761e5b5f253892a697941c71bac0159a1d74e/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py#L35).

You're correct in that the documentation isn't entirely correct, since [`multiprocessing.Queue` is indeed an alias for the `multiprocessing.context._default_context.Queue` factory](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58d761e5b5f253892a697941c71bac0159a1d74e/Lib/multiprocessing/__init__.py#L18-L23) that is defined [over here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58d761e5b5f253892a697941c71bac0159a1d74e/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py#L100-L103) and does

```
    def Queue(self, maxsize=0):
        from .queues import Queue
        return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
```

As an aside, if all you want to do is call `close()` on a queue at context manager exit time, use [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing):

```
q = Queue()
with contextlib.closing(q):
   # ...
```

Comment: OK - So the documentation is wrong. That's what I wanted to know. Thanks for the confirmation. It's unfortunate that multiprocessing.queues.Queue isn't properly documented. Specifically, there's no guidance on what should be provided for the required kwarg **ctx**.

Comment: @Pingu As you can see from the linked (and quoted) source, `_default_context` passes in `self.get_context()`. So, `MyQueue(maxsize, ctx=multiprocessing.context._default_context.get_context())` – and [since that function returns `self` when called without an argument](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58d761e5b5f253892a697941c71bac0159a1d74e/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py#L187-L189), `MyQueue(maxsize, ctx=multiprocessing.context._default_context)`.

Comment: You miss my point. You and I are both capable of reading and interpreting the code but there's no documentation *per se*. You've already confirmed that the documentation for multiprocessing.Queue is broken. That's all I needed to know. If I could I'd delete the question now as the responses are getting silly

Comment: I think the documentation glosses over the fact that the `multiprocessing.Queue` attribute is actually a factory because you're evidently not supposed to subclass `Queue`, because it isn't easy to do so. Anyway, I'm sorry my responses and help were too silly for you.